# Is it possible to Pass Values to a a function which accepts Array as parameter in C?

Tags: c

I have a function as follows:

```
void func1(unsigned char a[], unsigned char length)
{

// code here

}
```

is t possible for me to pass values like this?

```
func1(0x09,1); // array of 1 and length as 1

func1([0x09,0x02],0x02);
```

Comment: `func1( (unsigned char[]){9, 2}, 2 )`

Comment: @Yunnosch there's undoubtedly dozens of duplicate but i cbb searching

Comment: @M.M What is "cbb" ?

Comment: I would guess it's 'can't be bothered'. c: